# How to remove last item if is duplicate? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove last item only if duplicate.

Example:

Item with index 2 and 3 is same.

I want to remove last only if is duplicate. And expected array will be:

I am try with splice(-1, 1) but it no good result because i need to splice only if duplicate ( if last and penultimate is same )

What I am try:
3: [12.737223, 52.708065]

```
arr.splice(-1, 1)
```

**Help how to do ONLY IF LAST TWO DUPLICATE**

Important. There are always the last 2 items of problem. So you shouldn't remove a duplicate in the whole array but only the last index!

Comment: were is the specific problem with the task?

Comment: If there's a bug in your code causes a duplicate of the last element being generated occassionally. You should focus on fixing that instead of removing it afterwards IMO.

Comment: Those are floating  point numbers, do you want to remove them if they are nearly equal or exactly equal? If those number result from calculations they might never be exactly equal except if they result from the same sequence of operations.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [[10.117223, 50.118065],[11.229023, 51.228065], 
[12.737223, 52.708065],[12.737223, 52.708065]];

let last2El = arr.slice(-2);

if(last2El[0][1]===last2El[1][1] && last2El[0][2]===last2El[1][2]) 
   arr.splice(-1,1)

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
let arr = [
[10.117223, 50.118065],
[11.229023, 51.228065], 
[12.737223, 52.708065],
[12.737223, 52.708065]];

const len = arr.length;


arr[len-1].join() === arr[len-2].join() && arr.pop();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```js
let arr = [
  [10.117223, 50.118065],
  [11.229023, 51.228065],
  [12.737223, 52.708065],
  [12.737223, 52.708065],
];

if (arr.length >= 2) {
  const [a1, b1] = arr[arr.length - 2];
  const [a2, b2] = arr[arr.length - 1];

  if (a1 === a2 && b1 === b2) {
    arr.pop();
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```